# Next/previous page link on template receiving a notice

Tags: php, wordpress

I wanted to have previous and next buttons on certain template pages built in Wordpress. These pages are child pages, so should not go to it's parent or another child.

After reading numerous posts and looking at the code on Wordpress and here. I've come up with the below, but am receiving a **Notice: Undefined offset: 7 on line 94**,.

The line is:

```
$nextID = $pages[$current+1];
```

```
    <?php
    $pagelist = get_pages("child_of=".$post->post_parent."&parent=".$post->post_parent."&sort_column=menu_order title&sort_order=asc");
    $pages = array();
    foreach ($pagelist as $page) {
        $pages[] += $page->ID;
    }

    $current = array_search(get_the_ID(), $pages);
    $prevID = $pages[$current-1];
    $nextID = $pages[$current+1];
    ?>

    <div class="navigation">
    <?php if (!empty($prevID)) { ?>
        <div class="alignleft">
            <a href="<?php echo get_permalink($prevID); ?>" title="<?php echo get_the_title($prevID); ?>">Previous exhibitor</a>
        </div>
        <?php }
        if (!empty($nextID)) { ?>
        <div class="alignright">
            <a href="<?php echo get_permalink($nextID); ?>" title="<?php echo get_the_title($nextID); ?>">Next exhibitor</a>
        </div>
        <?php } ?>
    </div>
```

How do I remove the error so that when I get to the last page in the child, it disappears?

Comment: Can you highlight which code is causing the issue. We cannot determine line number 94 from here.

Comment: The line is: `$nextID = $pages[$current+1];` maybe it wasn't clear above.

Answer (score 0):

See if that array element `isset` or set `null`:

```
$nextID = $pages[$current + 1] ?? null;
```

[PHP Manual - Language Operators - Null Coalescing Operator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.coalesce)

This is the equivalent to:

```
$nextID = isset($pages[$current + 1]) ? $pages[$current + 1] : null;
```

Comment: you should get on a newer version of PHP `;)` ... i updated with alternate syntax

Comment: The `??` (Null Coalescing) operator only exists on PHP > 7.0.0